# How to assign char to char* in C?

Tags: c, char, assign

This code doesn't work.

```
char* randomWordHidden[length];
char try;

printf("Enter a letter: ");
scanf(" %c", &try);

//here there is a loop    
  randomWordHidden[i] = try; //assign position of randomWordHidden with try value
```

it gives error: [Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

But I do this and it works:

```
randomWordHidden[i] = "H";
```

How can i assign to a position of randomWordHidden the value of try var?

Answer (score 4):

Well;

you have made a list (of length `length`) of *pointers* to characters. I guess what you want is:

```
char randomWordHidden[length];
```

that should be `length` characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your `randomWordHidden` is not an array of `char`, but an array of `char*`, so effectively an array of strings. That's why assigning a `char` gives you a warning, because you cannot do `char* = char`. But the assignment of `"H"`, works, because it is *NOT* a `char` - it is a string (`const char*`), which consists of letter `'H'` followed by terminating character `'\0'`. This is `char` - `'H'`, this is string (`char` array) - `"H"`.

You most likely need to change the declaration of the `randomWordHidden` array to `char` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe arrays are already pointers, no need for that declaration.

*char randomWordHidden[length];*

Give that a try?